# Клонирование элемента и добавление ему атрибута

Tags: javascript, атрибуты

Есть следующий код

```
element = document.getElementsByName('rain');
function getRandomInt(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

let div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = "rain";

let test = div.cloneNode(true);
base = document.getElementsByTagName('article');

function add_rain() {
    base[0].append(test.setAttribute('animation', "go-left-right "+ getRandomInt(5) +"s infinite"));
}
setInterval(add_rain, 122)
```

В моем понимании есть донор - div, и я создаю клона и добавляю ему атрибут. Естественно это не работает. Пробовал другие варианты - не помогает (не знаю как).

Должен был получиться этакий дождь.

Comment: Спасибо! 
Готов выбрать Ваш ответ правильным)

Comment: увидев, что гуру ответил, я даже браться не стал. Но, раз Вам помогло, то решил добавить ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
let oBase = document.querySelector('article');
/* Генерация псевдослучайного числа */
function fGetRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}
// Создание образца капли/снежинки
let oDrop = document.createElement('div');
// Символ капли/снежинки
oDrop.innerHTML = '&#10052;';
// Общие стили для капли/снежинки
oDrop.className = "rain";

function add_rain() {
  // Создание клона капли/снежинки
  let oClone = oDrop.cloneNode(true);
  /* Обработчик конца анимации */
  oClone.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
    // Самоудаление элемента по завершению анимации
    this.remove();
  });
  // Установка начальной позиции по X
  oClone.style.left = `${1 + fGetRandomInt(98)}%`;
  // Назначение анимации
  oClone.style.animation = `go-left-right ${4 + fGetRandomInt(4)}s linear forwards`;
  // Добавление клона в нужный контейнер
  oBase.append(oClone);
}
/* Запуск */
setInterval(add_rain, 122);
```

```css
body{margin:0;height:100vh;background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9NKc.png),radial-gradient(#ff8800cc,#4527A0);background-position:0% 0%;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:auto}

article {
  position: relative; height: 100%; overflow: hidden;
  background-image: radial-gradient(#f321b221, #0d0023);
}
.rain {
  position: absolute; z-index: -1;
  display: inline-block; color: #fff;
}
@keyframes go-left-right {
  0% { top: -10%; transform: translatex(0px); }
  25% { transform: translatex(-5px); }
  50% { transform: translatex(10px); }
  75% { transform: translatex(-20px); }
  100% { top: 110%; transform: translatex(40px); }
}
```

```html
<article></article>
```

Comment: @Alexandr_TT: Да, я бы рад добавить. Но, два нюанса - траффик и доступность. Не раз уже было, что ссылки на картинки бились и вся красота и время на её поиски впустую.

Answer (score 3):

Метод [`.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) ничего не возвращает, поэтому при передаче результата в `append` ничего не происходит.

Вместо этого, передавать нужно сам элемент `test`.

```
test.setAttribute(...);
base[0].append(test);
```

---

Кроме того, недостаточно просто вызывать `append` с одним и тем же элементом. Чтобы было много элементов, каждый раз нужно создавать новый элемент, который будет добавлен на страницу, это значит, что клонирование так же нужно внести внутрь `add_rain`

Comment: Спасибо за совет. 
Я возможно не правильно объяснил, но, в результате, должен был получиться дождь).Используя ваш совет, как ни странно описание элемента менялось, а анимация - нет. Т.е. анимация была базовой(рассчитанной 1 раз в самом начале).
Таким образом, получалась "лесенка".

Помогло как ни странно "style.animation ="